# Отсутствует перевод в описании вопрос-дубликатов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, дубликаты

Посмотрел [один из моих вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1120946/176217) который отмечен как дубликат и заметил отсутствие перевода в следующих местах:

[image]

Важно! Указанный текст отображается только для автора вопроса.

Comment: И не спрашивайте почему я пересматриваю свои вопросы в 5 утра. (◕‿◕)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил переводы:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13776
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13779
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13771

Как обычно, вы можете сами предлагать переводы через сайт https://ru.traducir.win

Переводы появятся на сайте в составе свежих сборок. Текущая rev 2020.7.31.37311